# What causes timeouts in the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction method?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timeout, .net-4.5

Occasionally I see timeouts in the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction method. I haven't changed the default connection timeout value and unfortunately I am not seeing any entries in the event logs or in the profiler that relate to this timeout.

So I am a little bit lost, why a timeout during BeginTransaction occurs.

Does anybody know why BeginTransaction would time out? I guess it must be blocking on something, but am not sure what ressource that could be (if it's really a blocking issue).

(The database in question is not clustered/mirrored if that matters.) SQL Server 2008 Standard edition. The timeout occurs in a windows service that we wrote.

The detailed error message (English translation: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.)

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout abgelaufen. Das Zeitlimit wurde vor dem Beenden des Vorgangs überschritten oder der Server reagiert nicht. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Der Wartevorgang wurde abgebrochen
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
   bei Mmv.Shared.DatabaseLayer.SqlServer.RLSVerarbeitungObjectFactory.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
```

Comment: Is it possible that another process currently has opened a transaction (on the same database)? So maybe `BeginTransaction` would have to wait until that other transaction is committed (or rolled back)?

Comment: At BeginTransaction there isn't an actual sql command or similar issued, it's just a call to begin a transaction. So I wouldn't know why it had to wait for another transaction at this point.